How to update 100 of NuGet Package which is Vulnerable, Deprecated and Older version that is compatible with current code when Major Version Change
There are 150+ NuGet Package and some are Vulnerable, Some are Deprecated and most of the are not older version. I am updating NuGet Package one by one and see any incompatible issue arises. if any issue comes then I do revert that package and check whether app works. some time it is not working, so i have to do from beginning.
Most of the Version have Major change and some are minor change and some are patch change in version number assuming the NuGet Version follow
Semantic Versioning works by structuring each version identifier into three parts, MAJOR, MINOR, and PATCH. Each of these parts is managed as a number and incremented according to the following rules:
Major releases (2.0.0) indicate changes that will be incompatible with previous versions.
Minor releases (2.1.0) add functionality while still being backward-compatible (in this example 2.1.0 will be compatible with 2.0.0).
Patch releases are minor bug fixes or security patches that should always be fully backward compatible (2.1.4).
Is there a way to update all latest version that is only patch difference
similarly Minor.
How to find the incompatible change in major without updating and finding.
Please advise best approach.

So, what I would do, is simply update a NuGet package, fix the code it broke, then move onto another.  It's tedious, but with large systems of code and assets, you need to fix it one step at a time.
I'm sure you don't want to hear this, there isn't a fix-all-end-all magic wand way to fix it.
If you're up to the task, go for it. Your enterprise will appreciate your dedication on fixing and patching security holes in their application.
The only other option is the tried and true: "If it ain't broke, don't fix it."

That's true. It's tedious, but there is no fast track. To improve speed and can be helpful to open all .csproj files in Notepad++ and do a search and replace over all opened files. This can be faster, if you know the desired version number and you know it will work. And to not start over again, commit early, commit often. When you're done, squash the commits.
